# Windows 8 .NET framework 4

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows

My PC had Windows 8 installed with French (it's a French company where I work at). I changed it to be English however .net Framework 4 is still in French so all the errors that come from it are in French and thus it's harder to find help on the internet. When I try to reinstall the framework the installer says **"Microsoft .NET Framework 4 is already a part of this operating system. You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4 redistributable"**

How do I change .NET Framework 4 from French to English on my Windows 8 machine?

Thanks,

N.b. Serverfault people say this is off-topic.

Comment: Are you doing development? Or are you just trying to run an application that uses .NET? Why did you tag this as ASP.NET?

Comment: development. Developing in ASP.NET. Do you have a solution for this?